# Proof of the consistency of unbiased estimators

Tags: probability, statistics

Prove that $\hat{\theta}$ is an unbiased estimator of $\theta$ and $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}$ Var($\hat{\theta})=0$ then $\hat{\theta}$ is consistent.

Comment: Chebychev's inequality and the definition of consistency gives this immediately.

Comment: The word "if" is missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For consistency you need $P(\lvert \theta_n-\hat{\theta} \rvert)> \epsilon)\to 0$. Note by Chebyshev's inequality, $P(\lvert \theta_n-\hat{\theta} \rvert)\le \frac{E(\theta_n-\hat{\theta})^2}{\epsilon^2}$. Now $Var(\theta_n)=E(\theta_n-\hat{\theta})^2$, so the criterion for consistency is met.

Comment: Thank you! This is very helpful!